# How can I mark/save a question (of another user) to be notified upon new replies or edits?

Tags: support, feature-request

Is there a possibility to mark/save questions (of other users) so I would be notified upon new replies or edits?

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300671/236563

Comment: One way would be to "star" it, so you can get back to it later. But there's no notification by this.

Answer (score 1):

The closer you get, but you don't get any notification, is from questions you mark as favorite. When you then visit https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/64727/min-soo-pipefeet?tab=favorites, you will see highlighted on the top the questions with new edits or answers. (The edits are for both the question and the answers.)